# get the full image path of the image stored in the PhotoGallery

Tags: iphone

I want to get the full image path of the image stored in the PhotoGallery inside the iphone.How to get it? I used the image.nativePath But it's not working.. Please Help Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not possible.
You can only works on copy of photo

**Edit** : It should be possible to get the url of the file with:

```
- (NSURL *)url
```

of [`ALAssetRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009728) class

Comment: Here is my code sample.var image = event.media;      
       Ti.API.info('Our type was: '+event.mediaType);
       if(event.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO)
       {      
        imageView.image = image;
        Ti.API.info(' Selected Image1 ' + image.text);
       }

Comment: I just need the path of that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the actual path of the image, even if you get the path. Starting in iOS4 the access to the actual files is denied, while in iOS 3 it was possible.